# I can't set the root password for MySQL

Tags: mysql, passwords, mysql-error-1044

I've just set up a LAMP server using SuSE Server 10. I want to set the root password for MySQL, so I entered the following in the terminal:

```
mysqladmin -u root password MyPassword
```

and the output is:

```
mysqladmin: Can't turn off logging; error: 'Access denied; you need SUPER  
privilege for this operation'
```

I'm not really certain what SUPER privilege is for mysqladmin, and all my Google searches have been fruitless. I am able to use mysql from the command line without entering a password like this:

```
mysql -u root
```

But I can't access the mysql database to update the root password that way. Here is the output:

```
mysql> USE mysql;  
mysql> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure what the solution to this problem is, but the solution I came up with was to install SuSE 11. Everything is working now. I think there was just a problem with my initial install.